# Annotation stored in a database is not showing my leader lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, annotation

I am using 10.2.2, I initially tried to use just plain annotation to label my features. This however was not useful as it was very laggy and took at least 30 sec or more to choose each individual annotation. ESRI help did not have a clue as to why this was happening. We tested and showed that storing the annotation in a database was much quicker. This being said, I really need it to have leader 
lines, when I initially labeled the features I did make the label the way I liked with the leader lines, once it got into the annotation 
format in the database the leader lines mostly disappear and the ones that show up disappear when I adjust the label.

I am using Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise

[image: a snapshot of leaderlines, some show but when I move the annotation it dissappears]
[image: leaderline menu]

Any clue to why this is happening would be wonderful! This map was needed last week!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide screen shots of what's happening? When you edit the annotation class and right click on an annotation do you get any options to show the leader line?

Comment: i dont' know how to past a screen shot trying.  And I went to the attribute menue and the leader line is showing it should be there.

Comment: Are you editing with the annotation editor? 
When you click on a point and under the attributes --> leader what do you see?

Comment: It is attributed as I set

Comment: Just got off the phone with ESRI support and she can't figure it out either.  She sent it up to a specialist.

Comment: If you right click on the annotation while in annotation editor, do you have the option to "Add Leader"?

Comment: yes I do, and I clicked on it and it showed the annotation with a leader line.

Answer (score 2):

change your leader tolerance to zero (instead of 15) in the window shown above. Right now only leaders outside of the tolerance are visible (eg. point 31275 above). This change will make all of your leader lines show up, regardless of proximity the the feature you are labeling.

Comment: I think this is definitely a likely fix for the problem. As an aside, I would also move the road labels to be ON the line rather than on top so it will decrease congestion around the point labels.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was originally set to 1, I just changed it to 0 and I am still having the issue.  Also thanks for the advice on the road names, I have made them annotations so I can move them as I go.

Comment: In the capture above it shows a leader tolerance of 15 and a gap of 1. Make sure you are adjusting the tolerance value and not the gap value and see if things work better. Just FYI you have to adjust the tolerance for each annotation individually or you might be able to do a select all and change the values (I'm not 100% on that). That might be why it doesn't seem like it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and what helped me besides changing label gaps and tolerance was to select 'Disable substitutions' in the Symbology tab of the annotation layer properties. Before that I had 'Substitute individual symbols...' checked but even after unchecking it all the colors and fonts for different groups of labels stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally figured it out, well the ESRI support did, apparently in 10.2.2 there is a new editor curser you use for editing annotation.  It looks like this
[image: Anno Point tool]

So when you convert labels to annotation and store in a database, use this curser to edit.

Thanks to evey one who tried to help!

Niki

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug. I had the same exact issues. Finally, ESRI acknowledged it that it is a bug and they will try to fix it with the next patch coming out. The work around suggested for the time being was to have the database annotation.

Comment: can you provide the NIM# in your answer? Also explaining the workaround just a bit more. We prefer long answers to short. and this is more of a comment at the moment.